# jQuery dialog popup does not have a "x" in the close box in top right of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I have a jQuery popup and the "x" is not appearing in the close box in top right of popup.

[image]

I am using this example: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

I have included the link and script (two of each).

My html is:

```
  <div class="form-popup form-container autoScroll" id="myForm">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="riskTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>rkId</th>
                  <th>Risk Name</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="riskTablebody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#updateRisk').click(function() {
        $("#myForm").dialog({
            title: "Select Risks",
            width: 600, 
            modal: true, 
            resizable: true,
        });   
    });    
});
```

I want this as user friendly as possible so having the "X" in red would be an extra bonus!

My list of cdn libraries is:

```
<!-- Validate -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>

<!-- Confirm -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Date Picker-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Google Maps - not implemented due to cost -->
<!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>  -->

<!-- Le styles -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<!-- Confirm -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing including css file. Please add css to your html

Comment: Here you can find the JS and CSS bundled together https://jqueryui.com/download/all/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the jquery-ui.min.js has been broken since 1.10. So either:

- Install an earlier version; or
- Place the library after the bootstrap library (will adversely affect the bootstrap tooltip); or
- Resolve the conflict with the code below:

  ```
  $('#updateRisk').click(function() {
      if (typeof $.fn.bootstrapBtn =='undefined') {
          $.fn.bootstrapBtn = $.fn.button.noConflict();
      };

      $("#myForm").dialog({
          title: "Select Risks",
          width: 600, 
          modal: true, 
          resizable: true,
      });
      showRiskTable();
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the necessory libraries and it should work. Below is a working example.
Also i added a little css to hide the content before model opens.

```
#dialog{
  display:none;
}
```

Working Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/mrAhmedkhan/04goxq8h/11/

Comment: Thanks Mr Khan; however, what are the necessary libraries please? I have updated above with the full list of libraries I am including. What cdn am I missing please? I already had the hide.